# xdg-open ignores my application definitions

Tags: gnome, xdg-open

I am running **compiz-gnome** session with **xfdesktop** on **fc16**, don't ask why, but I have this weird problem. Some of the applications (e.g. tracker, or evolution )do not start the proper application for the appropriate filetype; instead nautilus is launched. I have checked under `./local/share/applications/` for the presence of the `.desktop` file, and `mimeapps.list` . I have debugged a bit and it seems that xdg-open does appropriate launch `gvfs-open`.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found out what is wrong, and it seems that I am affected by [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=674321) . The problem is that even though `exo-filemanager` had been updated the `mimeapps.list` file still contained the invalid entries. One has to manually edit the `mimeapps.list` and `mimeinfo.cache` and remove all the lines containing the `x-scheme-handler` lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your handler under both the `[Default Applications]` entry and `[Added Associations]` if it's a new one.

But anyway, why wouldn't you use thunar to achieve this easily, see the `Open With` box:
(You might just compare the mimeapps.list after changing the handler)

[image]